# Calendar added from API does not show up on google account

Tags: python, google-calendar-api

When adding a calendar to the google account we have for an application through the API, the event is added successfully and returns the calendars id that we store in our db. However when logging into the google account to look at the calendar created, there is no such calendar for the account.

```
new_cal = {
    'summary': calendar_name,
    'timeZone': pytz.all_timezones[timezone]
}
created_calendar = service.calendars().insert(body=new_cal).execute()
```

This is the code used to add the calendar to the google account

Comment: How was the calendar created, through a service account or a user's account? Also can you try using [CalendarList: list](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/list)?

Comment: I'm fairly certain it is done through the service account as the credentials are made through ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name. When these calendars are created they are visible through the CalendarList, but not visible on the actual google account.

Comment: service account and users account are not similar hence the expected outcome.

Comment: use user account oauth not service acxount if you want the calendars to appear on that certain user acct